# a and c keys not working on macbook, even on an external keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

It's a 2011 MacBook pro and the <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd> keys are not working on both the built-in keyboard and the usb keyboard.

Because of this i can't bypass the firmware login screen. 
Now the weird thing is that that <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> works (select all) so the key is being recognized, but <kbd>a</kbd> by itself doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: is it only the a and c keys?

Comment: As far as i can tell

Comment: How about option a and option c?  (å and ç on US layout)

Comment: That does nothing

Comment: Most likely there is/are key(s) stuck on the internal keyboard.  To diagnose, disconnect the keyboard from logic board and use an external keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by rebooting into safe mode as a troubleshooting step. Restart and hold down the shift key, when booted into safe mode you can test the keys:

Delete the preference file which can be found here  /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist

Restart normally

Comment: Cant boot into safemode because of firmware password. Firmware password appears instantly upon boot

Comment: Does your computer have a removable RAM? If so then you can take out one RAM stick and boot the computer by holding down CMD+ALT+P+R and allow the computer to reboot 3 times which should clear the firmware password.

Comment: I tried but it turns out that only works on pre 2010 macs.